# HTML5: Video-Tag with more source-Tag doesn't work

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I wanted to define several source-tags in a video-tag to define videos for different viewports. Unfortunately, does not work as desired? Is the approach correct or is there a possibility?

```
<video>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="..." media="(min-width:680px)">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="..." media="(min-width:1200px)">
</video>
```

Comment: This might be better as a question like: "How can I show different videos based upon the available client width" or something similar.  You're asking why a particular approach doesn't work (which is fine), but I'm guessing that the tags just don't work that way. What you're trying to do has probably been solved before, so I'd just ask how other people have solved it.

Comment: looks like the media query option on `<video>` has been deprecated (which IMO is sad because it would be handy), so you're probably going to have to track the browser width in JS and replace the source

Answer (score 0):

Put this link and change your links

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```